# Running RSpec causes wrong argument type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Running RSpec on a Rails app: When `valid?` is being called on an invalid record, RSpec crashes with the following output:

```
 TypeError:
   wrong argument type Hash (expected binding)
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was caused by the definition of a custom `binding` method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.

This is very annoying because I cannot test my models.

Looking at the backtrace, it seems to me that the error doesn't come from my App code.

I tried to upgrade rspec-rails to the lattest version and to change the versions of i18n gem and some other that seemed related, but a bit at random for lack of anything better. It kept having the exact same message. I googled every set of terms that seemed relevant to me, but could not find anything comparable.

**Would you know how to fix or proceed to fix this ?**

I'm not looking for self-patching an error outside of my app code, but rather for fixing my configuration, app or tests, should the case arise.

Below, a test demonstrating this behaviour, command, backtrace, and Gemfile.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Test:**

```
  1 require 'spec_helper'
  2 #require 'rspec-expectations'
  3
  4 describe User do
  5   before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)}
  6
  7   subject { @user }
  8
  9   it { should be_valid}
 10
 11   describe "test" do
 12     before { @user.email = "a" } #causing the model to be invalid
 13
 14     it "causes wrong argument type Hash (expected binding)" do
 15       puts "here 1"
 16       puts @user.method(:valid?).inspect
 17       puts @user.valid?
 18       puts "here 2"
 19     end
 20   end
 21 end
```

**In the console, it works as it should:**

```
R ~/dev/pav/spec rails c test
Loading test environment (Rails 4.1.0)
2.1.0 :001 > user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Example user1", email: "Example.user1@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$V1znGRLKwr09y2k.QSoL2egSVNkedh22ZWnn1r9B31/...", remember_token: nil, guide: nil>
2.1.0 :002 > user.email = "a"
 => "a"
2.1.0 :003 > user.valid?
  User Exists (5.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('a') LIMIT 1
 => false
```

**Command, output and backtrace:**

```
R ~/dev/pav rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -b
.here 1
#<Method: User(ActiveRecord::Validations)#valid?>
F

Failures:

  1) User test causes wrong argument type Hash (expected binding)
     Failure/Error: puts @user.valid?
     TypeError:
       wrong argument type Hash (expected binding)
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:176:in `eval'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:176:in `load_rb'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:166:in `load_file'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:40:in `available_locales'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/config.rb:41:in `available_locales'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/config.rb:47:in `available_locales_set'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n.rb:277:in `locale_available?'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n.rb:285:in `enforce_available_locales!'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n.rb:150:in `translate'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/naming.rb:187:in `human'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb:430:in `generate_message'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb:442:in `normalize_message'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb:293:in `add'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:32:in `record_error'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:8:in `validate_each'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:167:in `block in validate'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:164:in `each'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:164:in `validate'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `public_send'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:376:in `run_validations!'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:111:in `block in run_validations!'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:111:in `run_validations!'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:317:in `valid?'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in `valid?'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `call'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:340:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@pav/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Finished in 0.55629 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14 # User test causes wrong argument type Hash (expected binding)

Randomized with seed 26201
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com'
ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.1'
end
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.2'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'pg'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.2.2'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'html2haml'
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.5.3'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'orderly'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'hash_to_hidden_fields'
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'mousetrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'hashie'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is failing is as follows (from the top of your stacktrace):

```
    # Loads a plain Ruby translations file. eval'ing the file must yield
    # a Hash containing translation data with locales as toplevel keys.
    def load_rb(filename)
      eval(IO.read(filename), binding, filename)
    end
```

In this context, `binding` apparently evaluates to a Hash for some reason. You might try printing out that method here to see where it's coming from (e.g. `puts method(:binding).inspect`) to see if you can figure out what is overriding the kernel definition.

As a related aside, this i18n gem is not the same gem as you are loading, as you can see by the version number of the source directory.

Comment: i18n is a dependence of rails-i18n. Downgrading i18n did not do the trick.
`method(:binding).inspect` gives `I18n::Backend::Simple(ApplicationHelper)#binding` which seems normal. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: How are you concluding that that definition of `binding` is normal? It seems to be coming from `ApplicationHelper` rather than `Kernel`, which is the normal source of it in Rails.

Comment: I'm really not an expert on this matter. It seemed credible to me because it comes from a gem from svenfuchs (who also participates to rails-i18n) that is a dependence of I18n gem, in the [I18n module](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb), and because I suppose RSpec has to make some magic to run the tests.

Comment: I didn't find any reference to `binding` in the gem and assumed the `ApplicationHelper` was from your code. What do you get when you call `source_location` on the `method(:binding`)` result?

Comment: That's it: It gives me `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` on the line where I defined a `binding` method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your problem is, but this mixing of instance variables with subject blocks looks weird, try this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  it { should be_valid }

  context "email test" do
    subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: 'a') }

    it { should_not be_valid }

  end
end
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. Thanks for the good practice tip though!